# Catching exception across camel contexts

Tags: apache-camel

I have two routes - each in a different camel context:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <onException>
           <exception>com.me.MyException</exception>
           <to uri="log:osgiExecutorLog"/>
        </onException>

        <route id="MyRoute">
            <from uri="amq:test" />
                <to uri="direct:MyDirect"/>
        </route>
</camelContext>

<camelContext id="camelContext2" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">

        <route id="MyRoute">
            <from uri="direct:MyDirect" />
                <process ref="myProc"/>
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

There are conditions where myProc will throw MyException and I want the onException in camel context 1 to catch that. I tried my luck hard but could not get that to work; is it like catching exceptions across camel contexts not supported or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it necessary to use 2 separate contexts? Can you not just use 2 RouteBuilders in the one context?

Comment: @vikingsteve thanks for your comment; that's how it has been written earlier - I am trying to handle the exceptions at a common place so that I don't have to duplicate the code

Comment: Well I'm not really sure of the mechanisms in place but I would be tempted to redefine the exception handling in each context, exactly the same if necessary (all our contexts and route builders redefine the onException stuff at the top)

Comment: Btw, how is `direct:` working between camel contexts? My understanding was that you needed to use `vm:` component to communicate between contexts.

Comment: actually, it is the direct-vm component from Talend ESB that works across the vm!http://camel.apache.org/direct-vm.html

Comment: Aha, yes - that's it, thanks for the detail!. Alright, so instead of throwing an exception back to the other context, you could catch the exception and send a message to some sort of error handling endpoint. This can be easily defined in a different route builder or context, as long as you know the endpoint name. Each route has the same boilerplate handler e.g. `onException(blah).handled(true).to("direct-vm:errors")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to throw an exception back to the other context (which may or may not even be possible due to the mechanisms in camel 2.x) you could catch the exception and send a message to some sort of error handling endpoint.

This can be easily defined in a different route builder or context, as long as you know the endpoint name.

Each route then has exactly the same boilerplate exception handler at the top, for example:

```
onException(Exception.class).handled(true).to("direct-vm:errors")
```

We routinely use this sort of custom error handling between different route builders (in the same context, but the pattern can apply across contexts just as easily).

In our application, for example, we catch the exceptions, aggregate them in a list, and whenever 15 seconds goes by without a new exception we send an email via smtp - all too easy with a camel route defined as `from("direct:errors")...`

Comment: I think, this looks a fair solution; I was thinking to add beanRef where I can handle the exceptions but sending it to the direct-vm:error will be better too!

Comment: I think, I am having bit of bother with retries - it does not retry from the originator; will try my luck!

Comment: A bit late to the game, but I think this pattern only works if you have not transformed the message in the first route. That is, if you get an exception in the second route, and the input is the transformed message, then you can never send the original message to the error route. Then you need to throw an exception and let hte first route send it and use the original message instead.